We are trying to Map the cs files & cshtml files with URLs, is there any tool to do this mapping easily automatically
We are trying to Map the cs files & cshtml files with URLs into an excel file as shown in the pic below to check the impact analysis of a particular change, is there any tool to do this mapping easily or automatically, because going to every cshtml file, checking the controller methods and mapping to generate a URL is a tedious work, can anybody please suggest me, any suggestions would be greatly helpful. Thank you so much in advance. We are using ASP.NET MVC Razor architecture. Thank you so much again.


I think, to generate api document autometically, I used to use Swagger API,
I also don't know exactly what they can do, but I expect Swagger API can make the list of APIs as JSON and you may possible to convert it into CSV or Exel file.
I found this article and I hope this will help you
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/swagger-excel-sheets-wonderful-way-validating-rest-apis-aggarwal/
